CNN Network Audio Classification
Hi i'm new in audio classification machine learning/deep learning, and i'm trying to use a CNN to detect when a specific word is detected or not in my training loop the loss is 0.03, and the accuracy it's from 0.95 to 1 But in the test data the accuracy is 0.50 So i thing my model is just guessing if there is a word spoken or not and these results are after 5 Epoch, this is my code:
import os
import torchaudio
import torch
import torchmetrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch import nn
from torchaudio import transforms
import sounddevice
import numpy as np
import random
from torch.utils.data import random_split
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, random_split
from AudioUtil import AudioUtil
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from IPython.display import Audio
import librosa.display
import librosa
from torch.nn import init



audio = {'Path': [],
         'Class_Id': []}

for root, _, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\kirib\Desktop\PyTorch\Alexa Prototype\data\alexa_voice"):
    for file in files:
        audio['Path'].append(os.path.join(root, file))
        audio['Class_Id'].append(1)
        
        
for root, _, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\kirib\Desktop\PyTorch\Alexa Prototype\data\non_alexa_voice"):
    for file in files:
        audio['Path'].append(os.path.join(root, file))
        audio['Class_Id'].append(0)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(audio)


class SoundDS(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, df):
    self.df = df
    self.duration = 3500
    self.sr = 44100
    self.channel = 2
    self.shift_pct = 0.4
            
  # ----------------------------
  # Number of items in dataset
  # ----------------------------
  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.df)    
    
  # ----------------------------
  # Get i'th item in dataset
  # ----------------------------
  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    # Absolute file path of the audio file - concatenate the audio directory with
    # the relative path
    audio_file = self.df.loc[idx, 'Path']
    # Get the Class ID
    class_id = self.df.loc[idx, 'Class_Id']

    aud = AudioUtil.open(audio_file)
    # Some sounds have a higher sample rate, or fewer channels compared to the
    # majority. So make all sounds have the same number of channels and same 
    # sample rate. Unless the sample rate is the same, the pad_trunc will still
    # result in arrays of different lengths, even though the sound duration is
    # the same.
    reaud = AudioUtil.resample(aud, self.sr)
    rechan = AudioUtil.rechannel(reaud, self.channel)

    dur_aud = AudioUtil.pad_trunc(rechan, self.duration)
    shift_aud = AudioUtil.time_shift(dur_aud, self.shift_pct)
    sgram = AudioUtil.spectro_gram(shift_aud, n_mels=128, n_fft=1024, hop_len=None)
    aug_sgram = AudioUtil.spectro_augment(sgram, max_mask_pct=0.1, n_freq_masks=2, n_time_masks=2)

    return aug_sgram, class_id


dataset = SoundDS(dataframe)

num_items = len(dataset)
num_train = round(num_items * 0.8)
num_val = num_items - num_train
train_ds, val_ds = random_split(dataset, [num_train, num_val])

# Create training and validation data loaders
train_dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
val_dl = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

#train_features, train_labels = next(iter(train_dl))


#plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
#librosa.display.specshow(train_features[0][0].numpy(), sr=44100, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel')
#plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
#plt.title('Mel-spectrogram')
#plt.tight_layout()
#plt.show()

# Facciamo u modello
class AudioClassifier (nn.Module):
    # ----------------------------
    # Build the model architecture
    # ----------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=2,
                out_channels=16,
                kernel_size=3,
                stride=1,
                padding=2
            ),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )
        
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=16,
                out_channels=32,
                kernel_size=3,
                stride=1,
                padding=2
            ),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )
        
        self.conv3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=32,
                out_channels=64,
                kernel_size=3,
                stride=1,
                padding=2
            ),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )
        
        self.conv4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=64,
                out_channels=128,
                kernel_size=3,
                stride=1,
                padding=2
            ),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )
        
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(23040, out_features=1)

        
    # ----------------------------
    # Forward pass computations
    # ----------------------------
    def forward(self, x):
      x = self.conv1(x)
      x = self.conv2(x)
      x = self.conv3(x)
      x = self.conv4(x)
      x = self.flatten(x)
      x = self.linear(x)

      return x

myModel = AudioClassifier()
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
myModel = myModel.to(device)

# Check that it is on Cuda
#print(next(myModel.parameters()).device)

def training(model, train_dl, num_epochs):
  # Loss Function, Optimizer and Scheduler
  criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
  optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=0.1)
  scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.OneCycleLR(optimizer, max_lr=0.01,
                                                steps_per_epoch=int(len(train_dl)),
                                                epochs=num_epochs,
                                                anneal_strategy='linear')
  # Repeat for each epoch
  for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    running_loss = 0.0
    correct_prediction = 0
    total_prediction = 0

    # Repeat for each batch in the training set
    for i, data in enumerate(train_dl):
        # Get the input features and target labels, and put them on the GPU
        inputs, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)

        # Normalize the inputs
        inputs_m, inputs_s = inputs.mean(), inputs.std()
        inputs = (inputs - inputs_m) / inputs_s

        # Zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        logit = model(inputs).squeeze(1)
        loss = criterion(logit, labels.float())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()

        # Keep stats for Loss and Accuracy
        running_loss += loss.item()
        prediction = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(logit))
        
        # Count of predictions that matched the target label
        correct_prediction += (prediction == labels).sum().item()
        total_prediction += prediction.shape[0]

        if i % 10 == 0:    # print every 10 mini-batches
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' % (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 10))

    num_batches = len(train_dl)
    avg_loss = running_loss / num_batches
    acc = correct_prediction/total_prediction
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch}, Loss: {avg_loss:.2f}, Accuracy: {acc:.2f}')

    
torch.save(myModel.state_dict(), r"C:\Users\kirib\Desktop\PyTorch\Models\Wake_Word_Model.pt")
    
    
num_epochs=3   # Just for demo, adjust this higher.
training(myModel, train_dl, num_epochs)

def inference (model, val_dl):
  correct_prediction = 0
  total_prediction = 0

  # Disable gradient updates
  with torch.no_grad():
    for data in val_dl:
      # Get the input features and target labels, and put them on the GPU
      inputs, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)

      # Normalize the inputs
      inputs_m, inputs_s = inputs.mean(), inputs.std()
      inputs = (inputs - inputs_m) / inputs_s

      # Get predictions
      outputs = model(inputs)

      # Get the predicted class with the highest score
      _, prediction = torch.max(outputs,1)
      # Count of predictions that matched the target label
      correct_prediction += (prediction == labels).sum().item()
      total_prediction += prediction.shape[0]
    
  acc = correct_prediction/total_prediction
  print(f'Accuracy: {acc:.2f}, Total items: {total_prediction}')

# Run inference on trained model with the validation set
inference(myModel, val_dl)

And the method of my class AudioUtil are there:
import os
import torchaudio
import torch
import torchmetrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch import nn
from torchaudio import transforms
import sounddevice
import numpy as np
import random
from torch.utils.data import random_split
import math, random
import torch
import torchaudio
from torchaudio import transforms
from IPython.display import Audio

class AudioUtil():
  
    @staticmethod
    def open(audio_file):
        """Apre un audio file con torchaudio"""
        signal, sample_rate = torchaudio.load(audio_file)
        return (signal, sample_rate)
    
    @staticmethod
    def rechannel(audio, new_channel): 
        """cambia i canali di un audio presi da un input."""
        sig, sr = audio

        if (sig.shape[0] == new_channel):
          # Nothing to do
          return audio

        if (new_channel == 1):
          # Convert from stereo to mono by selecting only the first channel
          resig = sig[:1, :]
        else:
          # Convert from mono to stereo by duplicating the first channel
          resig = torch.cat([sig, sig])

        return ((resig, sr))
    
    @staticmethod
    def resample(audio, newsr):
        """Aggiusta l'audio in un altra frequenza"""
        sig, sr = audio

        if (sr == newsr):
          # Nothing to do
          return audio

        resig = torchaudio.transforms.Resample(sr, newsr)(sig)

        return ((resig, newsr))

    @staticmethod
    def pad_trunc(audio, max_ms):
        sig, sr = audio
        num_rows, sig_len = sig.shape
        max_len = sr//1000 * max_ms

        if (sig_len > max_len):
          # Truncate the signal to the given length
          sig = sig[:,:max_len]

        elif (sig_len < max_len):
          # Length of padding to add at the beginning and end of the signal
          pad_begin_len = random.randint(0, max_len - sig_len)
          pad_end_len = max_len - sig_len - pad_begin_len

          # Pad with 0s
          pad_begin = torch.zeros((num_rows, pad_begin_len))
          pad_end = torch.zeros((num_rows, pad_end_len))

          sig = torch.cat((pad_begin, sig, pad_end), 1)

        return (sig, sr)
 
    @staticmethod
    def time_shift(aud, shift_limit):
        sig,sr = aud
        _, sig_len = sig.shape
        shift_amt = int(random.random() * shift_limit * sig_len)
        return (sig.roll(shift_amt), sr)   
    
    @staticmethod
    def spectro_gram(aud, n_mels=64, n_fft=1024, hop_len=None):
        sig,sr = aud
        top_db = 80

        # spec has shape [channel, n_mels, time], where channel is mono, stereo etc
        spec = transforms.MelSpectrogram(sr, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_len, n_mels=n_mels)(sig)

        # Convert to decibels
        spec = transforms.AmplitudeToDB(top_db=top_db)(spec)
        return (spec)

    @staticmethod
    def spectro_augment(spec, max_mask_pct=0.1, n_freq_masks=1, n_time_masks=1):
        _, n_mels, n_steps = spec.shape
        mask_value = spec.mean()
        aug_spec = spec

        freq_mask_param = max_mask_pct * n_mels
        for _ in range(n_freq_masks):
          aug_spec = transforms.FrequencyMasking(freq_mask_param)(aug_spec, mask_value)

        time_mask_param = max_mask_pct * n_steps
        for _ in range(n_time_masks):
          aug_spec = transforms.TimeMasking(time_mask_param)(aug_spec, mask_value)

        return aug_spec


Bump?
????????s
